# A problem about real analysis :L^p Space

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I=[0,1],M_1,M_2>0$,
$$
S=\{f\in L^1(I)\cap L^p(I)| ||f_1||\le M_1,||f||_p\le M_2\}
$$

Show that for any given $\delta>0,\exists M>0$,such that for any $f\in S$
$$
\int_{x\in I;|f|>M} |f|<\delta
$$

I have no idea about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M>0$, let $f \in S$.

you have, $\lambda(|f|>M) M < \int_{|f|> M} |f|\leq \int_I |f| \leq M_1 $, (where $\lambda(A)$ is the measure of a set A).

So for all $M>0$ and all $f \in S$ you have   $\lambda(|f|>M) < \frac{M_1}{M}$.

By Hölder inequality there exist $q$, such that for all $M>0$ and all $f \in S$, $\int_{|f|> M} |f|= \int_I |f| 1_{|f|>M} \leq ||f||_p (\lambda(|f| > M))^{1/q} < M_2(\frac{M_1}{M})^{1/q} $.

Let $\delta>0$, you take $M=\frac{M_1 M_2^q}{\delta^q}$.